# How to connect two subgraphs with inter-edges?

Tags: python, networkx

Let `G1,G2,G3` be three graphs. Each of which has `N[i]` nodes.

Let the `3x3` matrix `A` represent the probability of contact between nodes of the disjoint graphs `G1,G2,G3`.

So `A_ij` indicates the probability of node at `Gi` to have an edge with a node at `Gj`.

`Aii` will be the probability to have an edge between nodes at `Gi`.

I need some help in doing it and also naming the nodes in such a way that in the union graph I will be able to see which nodes came from which `Gi`

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.2], [0.4, 0.1, 0.5], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]])
N = [20,30,40]

def get_number_edges(A,N,n):
    return int(A[n-1,n-1]*N[n-1])

G1=nx.dense_gnm_random_graph(N[0],get_number_edges(A,N,1))
G2=nx.dense_gnm_random_graph(N[1],get_number_edges(A,N,2))
G3=nx.dense_gnm_random_graph(N[2],get_number_edges(A,N,3))

C=nx.disjoint_union(nx.disjoint_union(G1,G2),G3)
```

1. I am not sure how to connect nodes from `Gi` to `Gj` where `i!=j`
2. I am not sure how to annotate the nodes at `C` with a label that indicates from which graph `Gi` there are originated.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create the full graph `C` and then create the subgraphs, if needed.

```
import itertools
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.2], [0.4, 0.1, 0.5], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]])
N = [20,30,40]

# create a square probability matrix with dimensions (total nodes, total nodes)
# and populate it with the values given in A
indices = []
ctr = 0
for n in N:
    indices.append(list(range(ctr, ctr+n)))
    ctr += n

# TODO: 
# remove this horrible triple loop; 
# have a cold and am not smart enough to do it properly now
total_nodes = sum(N)
probability = np.zeros((total_nodes, total_nodes), dtype=np.float)
for ii, sources in enumerate(indices):
    for jj, targets in enumerate(indices):
        for source, target in itertools.product(sources, targets):
            probability[source, target] = A[ii, jj]
plt.imshow(probability, cmap='gray'); plt.show()

# convert probability matrix into an adjacency matrix
adjacency = probability >= np.random.rand(*probability.shape)
plt.imshow(adjacency, cmap='gray'); plt.show()

# create networkx graph object
C = nx.from_numpy_array(adjacency)

# to get any subgraph, use the indices
G1 = C.subgraph(indices[0])
# etc
```

Comment: Isn’t there a way to avoid this loop or to using networkx API to mimic this?

Comment: @0x90 Not that I am aware of.